# попытка Inteleji IDEA достучаться к локальному серверу mysql выдает ошибку соединения

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

Дано:
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6 (Ultimate Edition), JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b22 amd64, Windows 10 10.0
Также локально установлен сервер Mysql 8.0.13. Через Workbench все базы видятся нормально. Сервер запущен. При попытке из IDEA достучаться до сервера выдает ошибку соединения. Причем если случаться на амазоновские сервера, то всё окей. Т.е. драйвер нормальный.

Вопрос, что может генерировать такую проблему и как её решить?

[image: ошибка подключения к локальному серверу mysql]

Comment: В 8 мускуле изменился механизм аутентификации. Еще не все программы умеют к нему коннектиться

Comment: Ну так на амазоновский 8 mysql достукивается

Comment: возможно там пользователь создан в режиме совместимости через `ALTER USER 'mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mysqlUsernamePassword';`